# Android Things app(UART port on Ras Pi) got Exception "Caller lacks required permission com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO"

Tags: xamarin.android, raspberry-pi, android-things

I am developing Android Things project to build and run on a Raspberry Pi 3 using Visual Studio(Xamarin Android). I can successfully deploy the app to Raspberry pi and I got the

> java.lang.SecurityException: Caller lacks required permission
>   com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO

error when app was initializing `UART` port. I have the following permission added in the `manifest.xml` file already and tried to uninstall-reboot-reinstall app route(advised by other people online) but got no luck.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.MANAGE_INPUT_DRIVERS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO" />
```

I am running Visual Studio 15.7.5 and Android Things 1.0.2. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try manually granting permissions through ADB? https://github.com/TilesOrganization/support/wiki/How-to-use-ADB-to-grant-permissions

Comment: @NickFelker Thank you very much. Manually granting permission works.